# Echo ordered like book's indexes

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I have a script that modifies all files in a directory and outputs in terminal the status of the modifications in real time, like this example:

```
Modifying json.php...   MODIFIED
Modifying layout.php...     ERROR
Modifying a_very_long_named_file.php...     NOT MODIFIED
```

I'm wondering if there is some command I can use to echo like in an ordered book's index, like this:

```
Modifying json.php..........................MODIFIED
Modifying layout.php........................ERROR
Modifying a_very_long_named_file.php........NOT MODIFIED
```

Comment: is it ok if you do the change in vim? I add a vim solution as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do it with echo, put I find printf more satisfying:

```
printf "Modifying ...................................\033[11G%s\033[35G%s\n" \
    $filename ERROR
```

Will print the filename starting at column 11, and print ERROR at column 35,
with .... in between.  If the filename is too large to fit, it will be partially
overwritten.

Or:

If you always have one space after 'Modifying', you could try:

```
< input column -t | tr ' ' . | sed 's/\./ /'
```

This requires all of the output to available, so that the maximum width can be determined before any data is produced.  Since you say "real time", that is probably not desirable, in which case you could use something like:

```
echo Modifying json.php MODIFIED | perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $F[1]", "...",
    "." x ( 30 - length( $F[1] )), $F[2]'
```

To print "...." that is 33 columns wide (adjust as desired).  If any file name is too long, that row will be too wide, but there's really no way to determine the maximum width required unless you wait for all of the data to be available.  (Unless you have access to all the file names before you start.  Pick a suitable width.)  The extra `"..."` is there to have at least some dots printed on wide rows, rather than concatenating the file name with the message.

Answer (score 1):

based on your input data, the line below works: (gawk needed)

```
 awk -F '\\.\\.\\. +' -vd=50 '{x=sprintf("%-"d"s   %s",$1,$2);gsub(/  /,"..",x);print x}' file
```

test

```
kent$  cat s
Modifying json.php...   MODIFIED
Modifying layout.php...     ERROR
Modifying a_very_long_named_file.php...     NOT MODIFIED

kent$  awk -F '\\.\\.\\. +' -vd=50 '{x=sprintf ("%-"d"s   %s",$1,$2);gsub(/  /,"..",x);print x}' s
Modifying json.php..................................MODIFIED
Modifying layout.php................................ERROR
Modifying a_very_long_named_file.php................NOT MODIFIED
```

note

- you change the number (50 in my example) to what you want
- the gsub(..) part is a little bit risky. it changes two connected spaces to two dots. but I think it wouldn't be big problem at the end there is a space left. (before Error/Modified...).

**EDIT**

add a vim solution, if you feel playing text in vim is comfortable

- type `set ve=all`
- remove those spaces after three dots (...)  `:%s/\. \+/\./g`
- cursor at first line, type `qa$vT.x55|pF.v55|r.jq`
- then `20@a`

all key-typing operations are in code block, not so much actually. this will do this text transformation in 20 lines, you could change 20 to 200 or 999 if you have many lines to do. Also this will move your "MODIFIED" etc to 55th column. you could change the number too.

if you do it in vim, it will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering in a such complete way, however I needed a solution for real time echoing texts. I loved that .gif, how did u made it?!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
   dots=.................................................
   echo Modifying $file ${dots:${#file}} $msg
```

This send a substring of dots to echo as the 3rd argument, but is
not standard sh.  (Works in bash.)